dovecot complains about fd limit ulimit (local IMAP server use), default_client_limit
I've been getting warnings like this:

dovecot Warning: fd limit (ulimit -n) is lower than required under max. load (256 < 1000), because of default_client_limit

in the dovecot logs. And MailMate would show a number of imap folders with the spinning loading indicator. The account did work, though.
This is dovecot v2.3.21.1 on macOS Sequoia 15.1 (24B83) installed via homebrew.

The solution was to decrease the default_client_limit (in my case to 10).
# conf.d/10-master.conf
default_client_limit = 10

(this is probably a very bad idea for any production environment)
